# Create a json file , write Json data into it and Load the file into JsonDataAccess in bb 10 cascades

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have this method call

```
QList<QByteArray> SocketBase::readAllSymb(QTcpSocket *socket) {

QList<QByteArray> listAll;
int bytesAvail = waitForInput(socket);

if (bytesAvail > 0) {
    //int symbolCount = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    bool endOfLine = false;
    bool endOfStream = false;


    while (cnt < bytesAvail && (!endOfLine) && (!endOfStream)) {

         QByteArray ba="";

         ba=socket->readAll();

         listAll.append(ba);

         if(ba.endsWith(']')){
             endOfStream = true;
         }
         ba="";
    }
}

return listAll;
```

}

now my Question is How to create a Dynamic file programatically and write data in to the file and load it like ....
      JsonDataAccess jda;

```
  QVariant list = jda.load(QDir::currentPath() +
                     "/app/native/assets/employees.json");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save a QMap to a file:

```
QFile file("out.txt");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
     qWarning() << "Couldn't open file";
     return;
}

JsonDataAccess jda;
jda.save(map, &file);
```